# Is there a correct grammatical way to state computer model number in plural form?

Tags: grammatical-number, writing

For example if I said -

> "I shipped ten Dell 360s this morning".

where *Dell 360* is the model number and I don't want people to get confused by the "**s**", how should I write this?

Is it more correct to mention the word laptop? 
For example :

> "I shipped ten Dell 360 laptops today".

The reason I didn't do this was because I'm not sure if they are considered laptops or notebooks etc. Could an apostrophe be used?

Comment: You can go with the more generic "systems" instead of "laptops" if you want to sidestep the issue properly....

Comment: as suggested above; I shipped ten Dell 360 systems this morning.

Comment: The original is just fine: you shipped some Dell 360s.  If the *360s* were a model number, then you would have said that you had shipped some Dell 360ses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to part of the original question: no, an apostrophe is not grammatically appropriate in this situation.

The generic word "systems," as mentioned previously, is really your safest bet.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should write as the following:

> I shipped ten pieces of Dell 360 this morning.

Note: I advise using *piece* because it is used for non-countable nouns.

Comment: That actually sounds awful =/

Comment: I would not suggest this. However the idea has some merit. Hardware is usually shipped in *units*, so "I shipped 10 Dell 360 units this morning".